# A property of the upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $A$ is a strictly upper triangular n × n matrix, i.e. $A_{ij} = 0$ if $j \leq i$. Show that exp($tA$) is a polynomial of degree $n$ in the variable $t$ with
matrix coefficients. For the exponential of a matrix $B$ use the power series
formula:
$$
\exp(B)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{B^j}{j!}
$$
Show that the vector equation $\partial_{t}X(t) = AX(t)$ always has a non-zero solution that is bounded for all $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$ . Here $X(t)$ is an n × 1-vector valued
function.

My confuses is:

1) all the eigenvalues of A must be $0$, so the characteristic polynomial of A is $f(\lambda)=\lambda^n.$ According to Caylay's Theorem, $f(A)=A^n=0$, so $\exp(tA)$ should be a polynomial of degree $n-1$ instead of $n$.

2) In the second part of this problem, I can get the solution matrix $X(t)=e^{At}$. But how to prove it has a bounded solution for all $t$?

Comment: For 2), your solution is not quite correct since $X(t) = e^{At}$ is a matrix-valued function. I think you want $X(t) = e^{At}X(0)$ to ensure that $X(t)$ is an $n \times 1$ vector (where $X(0)$ is an $n \times 1$ initial vector).

Comment: $X(t)$ is a solution matrix in which every column is a solution and mutually linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1), it seems you are correct. Perhaps the confusion is that with the $0$th term, there are $n$ terms in an $n-1$ polynomial.

For 2), any solution should have the form $X(t) = e^{At}X(0)$. The only hope you have for this to be bounded in general is by wisely selecting the initial vector $X(0)$. Now, you have that 
$$
e^{At} = I + At + \cdots + \frac{A^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} t^{n-1}
$$
Since $A$ is strictly upper triangular, then $A^k$ is also for any $k \geq 1$. In particular, $e^{At}$ will be an upper triangular matrix with $1$s down the diagonal. Try choosing $X(0) = (1, 0, 0, ..., 0)^T$ and see what happens.

Comment: In this question, the Identity matrix $I$ in the right side is not exist, so...

Comment: It should. The standard convention for the exponential is that $$\exp(B) = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{B^j}{j!}  = I + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{B^j}{j!}$$ In fact, for $\partial_t e^{At} = Ae^{At}$ you need the identity matrix.. just like for the standard exponential on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK, and can you tell me what does "1s" mean?

Comment: All diagonal entries are the number 1, coming from the identity matrix.